# Have there been any dragons in warcraft that took a shape other than elf or human?

Tags: warcraft

In the Warcraft universe, dragons can take the shape of a humanoid.  Outside of Chromie(gnome), Kalecgos(half-elf), and Ebonhorn(Highmountain Tauren), have there been any dragons who a shape outside of human or elf?  We can also exclude the Ysera and Alexstraza, as their forms are different as well.

Comment: you gave quite a list of dragons who do, lol

Comment: @Himarm I realize that now, I was curious if there were any trolls or orc dragons

Comment: If you specifically want orc or troll examples, you may want to edit the question to reflect that.  As it stands, you might end up getting more examples of tauren-form dragons, etc.

Comment: @Steve-O I'm fine with any really.

Comment: I don't see any point excluding a few specific examples. Answers will be better if they have all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some examples follow.

Blue Dragonflight:

- [Arygos](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Arygos) took the shape of a gnome.
- [Andorgos](https://classic.wowhead.com/npc=15502/andorgos) took the shape of a gnome.
- [Kalecgos](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Kalecgos) took the form of a half-elf.

Bronze Dragonflight:

- [Eternos](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Eternos) takes the shape of a gnome.
- [Kairozdormu](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Kairozdormu) took both the shape of an Blood Elf and the shape of an Orc, on different moments.
- [Chromie](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Chronormu) took the form of a gnome.

Red Dragonflight:

- [Acridostrasz](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Acridostrasz) took the shape of an Blood elf and the shape of an Orc on different moments.
- [Rheastrasza](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Rheastrasza) took the shape of a goblin.

Black Dragonflight:

- [Ebonhorn/Ebyssian](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Ebyssian) took the shape of a Highmountain Tauren.

Comment: Why are most these dragons going around as gnomes specifically?

Comment: @Harabeck To be honest, it seems to boil down to personal preference of each dragon. There doesn't seem to be a "need" for them to pick this or that race when changing into an humanoid shape. I think it isn't any difference from a player choosing to play as Gnome on WoW, in the end.

Comment: @T.Sar maybe the players in WoW are really dragons?

Comment: @CBredlow If you go by people's RP profiles around the Blue Recluse, that wouldn't be far from the truth.